# IPad App Issue - Webview

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.2

I developing a Ipad application I am trying to use Webview but not able to open the URL in webview I am using following code

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"] autorelease];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

this code working well for Iphone app not not working for Ipad app. Is anything wrong.

Thanks Amit Battan

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize webView object?

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
```